# Function not running at page ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code set like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     select_a_color();
});

function select_a_color(){
     var myColors = ["#441540",
     "#20A923",
     "#EF5918",
     "#E33EF3",
     "#C6452B",
     "#F94B34",
     "#236BD4",
     "#51A224",
     "#6E3372"];
     var gencolor = myColors[Math.round(Math.random() * (myColors.length - 1))];
     alert(gencolor);
}
```

Each time I call the function, it's supposed to change `gencolor` and (for test) `alert` with the value for `gencolor`. I need this to run when my page loads initially, as an AJAX query needs the color, but I can't get it to run when my page loads. Note that when it's not a function, `gencolor` is generated correctly.

I end up with errors that gencolor is not defined.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE EDIT**: Made some changes, and I get the function to run, but it won't pass the variable `gencolor` correctly.

```
var gencolor;
function selectColor(gencolor){
    var myColors = ["#441540",
        "#20A923",
        "#EF5918",
        "#E33EF3",
        "#B46BF9",
        "#D95AA3",
        "#622469",
        "#FB5AE8",
        "#51A224",
        "#6E3372"];
    var gencolor = myColors[Math.round(Math.random() * (myColors.length - 1))];
    alert(gencolor); //THIS WORKS!
}

function load_test_map2(gencolor) {
    selectColor();//THIS SUCCESSFULLY TRIGGERS THE FUNCTION AND ALERT WORKS
    console.log(gencolor); //THIS IS UNDEFINED
}
```

I'm trying to pass the `gencolor` variable into this other function, but it's obviously not working.

Comment: Why are you doing your `$(document).ready()` *inside* of the `load_test_map2` function?

Comment: `gencolor` only exists inside the `select_a_color` function.

Comment: The code you posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ghw08hj3/

Comment: @RocketHazmat That was just one of the million things I tried. to ensure that the function is ran when the `load_test_map2` function is called. I only need `select_a_color` to run when `load_test_map2` is run first, but then need `select_a_color` to run several other times independently after `load_test_map2` loads.

Comment: I can confirm, this is correct Javascript and works as expected.

Comment: @FelixKling  Just updated my question, got the code to run, but it still doesn't pass the variable correctly.

Comment: `var gencolor = myColors[...];` creates a **local** variable which shadows the global variable.

Comment: @FelixKling That makes sense. How can I change this so that this becomes the global variable?

Comment: @FelixKling If I remove the `var` to have `gencolor = myColors[...]`, I'm still getting undefined errors in my second function.

Comment: The other problem is that the *parameter* `gencolor` shadows the global variable as well. So the definition should be `function load_test_map2() { ... }`. However, the best solution would be to forget about globals and simply `return gencolor;` from `selectColor`. Then do `console.log(selectColor());`.

Comment: I've got it. I had `function selectColor(gencolor){` but needed `function selectColor(){`

Comment: Oh yeah... there as well. But again, if you can avoid globals, you should. Makes your code much easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                select_a_color();
            });

        function select_a_color(){
        var myColors = ["#441540",
        "#20A923",
        "#EF5918",
        "#E33EF3",
        "#C6452B",
        "#F94B34",
        "#236BD4",
        "#51A224",
        "#6E3372"];
        var gencolor = myColors[Math.round(Math.random() * (myColors.length - 1))];
        console.log(gencolor);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Doing this and looking into the console and also refresh the page, I get following outputs:

`#F94B34`
`#51A224`
`#E33EF3`
`#F94B34`
..

So it seems to work.
Also do `console.log( message )` instead of `alert()`.
Also do you have included jQuery **before** the script?

Answer (score 0):

I see in your edit history that the original code is

```
function load_test_map2() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        select_a_color();
    });

function select_a_color(){
var myColors = ["#441540",
"#20A923",
"#EF5918",
"#E33EF3",
"#C6452B",
"#F94B34",
"#236BD4",
"#51A224",
"#6E3372"];
var gencolor = myColors[Math.round(Math.random() * (myColors.length - 1))];
alert(gencolor);
}
```

There are just two mistakes

1. You forgot to close the `load_test_map2()` function. But lets assume you just forgot to copy the closing braces.
2. You do not have to next these two functions within `load_test_map2` but if you do, you need to call it.

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghw08hj3/1/) which is a modification of your original code

Comment: `function load_test_map2() {` is loooong gone. The OP removed that line before anybody answered. See: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29305347/2

Comment: Wow, how fast do these things go! :D, thank you for the notification.

Comment: Well... that was 30 min ago. I'd say the most edits happen in the first 10min. You guys just have to refresh the page more often, or pay more attention to the "this question has been edited" banner thingy :P

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few minor mistakes--mostly the declration of the var gencolor inside the selectColor function, after declaring it globally.

This works fine (see it [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwa7Lwnw/)):

```
//global var
var gencolor;

$(document).ready(function() {
     load_test_map2();
});

function selectColor(){
     var myColors = ["#441540",
     "#20A923",
     "#EF5918",
     "#E33EF3",
     "#C6452B",
     "#F94B34",
     "#236BD4",
     "#51A224",
     "#6E3372"];
     // set the global var, don't redeclare it
     gencolor = myColors[Math.round(Math.random() * (myColors.length - 1))];
}

function load_test_map2() {
    selectColor();
    alert(gencolor); 
}
```